# Webservice returns null value while consuming in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

web service return type is Array of key and value pair. that is :

```
namespace WebReference
{
    [Serializable]
    [GeneratedCode("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.18408")]
    [XmlType(Namespace = "http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap")]
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    [DesignerCategory("code")]
    public class mapItem
    {`enter code here`
        public mapItem();

        [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
        public object key { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
        public object value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

--> I  have consumed like below....

```
//created proxy class
        WebReference.IngeniumCMSWebServService ws = new WebReference.IngeniumCMSWebServService();
//Accessed webservice method  Here I getting null value
        WebReference.mapItem[] items = ws.getPolicyInquiryAllDetails(polacyNumber);
        //string ff = dictionary[gg.key].ToString();

        Logger.LogMessage("====================================================================");
        foreach (var item in items)
        {

            Logger.LogMessage("key: " + item.key + "   Value: " + item.value);
        }
        Logger.LogMessage("====================================================================");
    }

}
```

I am getting null value at Items at the time of accessing the method...

Please guide me, how can I get values...
 web service link is correct , in other way I got the xml file and I have checked that xml, there are values...If I following this way, I'm not getting values , its showing null value.

Comment: Can you show us the webmethod's code?

Comment: That is client web methods, I don't have code.

Comment: OK. `items` is null or the value of item.value?

Comment: Items object is null..

Comment: Sometimes when you consume the web reference and after that you change something some things can break if you do not update de web reference. Have you tried it?